# How do you create a custom Role in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Under Roles there is no button for Create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do check your permissions for creating a role, If you are system administrator and not able to see create Custom role, please do contact MC Support team they will help you out

NOTE: It depends on which edition of MC you are using also counts into picture

Usually it will be like this below
[image]

You can compare Edition Features in the below url
[Editions and its features](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/mc_email_journey_pricing_sheet.pdf)

Comment: Many accounts actually just don't have it activated out of the box. Call up SFMC support and they should be able to turn it on.